# Android: add page before zeroth position dynamically in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with three pages 0,1 and 2. By default the pager should display page at position 1. When I swipe left and reach 0'th position. I want to add a new page say N before the 0'th page so that I can swipe again to reach the page N and mean while remove page 2. Once I reach N again I want to add one new page before N and remove the last page of viewpager, so that I can have only three pages in viewpager in total. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: May be you should show us some code for what have you done so far.

Comment: Hey @SubinSebastian I don’t know how to do this that’s why I asked the question.

Comment: Generally view pagers have associated adapters (ViewPagerAdapter) which does this job for you. Checkout the implementation examples, and expand you question with additional details and specific issues you are facing. I think what you are trying to achieve is possible.

Comment: I know to use view pager and also know how to use ViewPagerAdapter, FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. My question is, Is it possible to add a new page before the 0'th position? If yes, then how.